# Dense subsets in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: calculus, analysis, lp-spaces, approximation-theory

Which of the following are dense subsets in metrical space $L^1(\mathbb{R})$?

- set of smooth functions $C_0^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ with compact supports;
- set of above-mentioned functions' derivatives $\{f':f\in C_0^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})\}$;
- set of all simple functions with compact supports.

I'd really appreciate your help with this question. How do I check if a set is dense in this space?

Comment: @user99680 The approximation should be with respect to the $L^1$ norm.

Comment: A hint for the second part: the integral of such a function is 0.